# Is there any UI library in Android ,similar to the UI view of , iOS HealthBook/Passbook app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, cardlayout

I have to implement UI in Android similar to iOS HealthBook/Passbook app as below. 
 Video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0HkWgmeIlc

blog URL: http://loumiranda.com/2014/03/17/will-healthbookpassbook-be-a-new-ui-paradigm-in-ios-8/

I have searched but couldn't find any related libraries. I looked into expandable listviews and cards,
 but I want them to be stacked one on one.

1. Are there any such libraries?
2. Can I achieve this in any other way?
   Any suggestions and links will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you implement this UI feature in android or not? because i also want to apply this feature in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is not direct library by which you can make it , you have to use custom layout .

Comment: how we can implement using costume view?