# how to create UI like Healthbook animation list view in ios app

Tags: android, listview, animation

I want to develop animated list view like Healthbook app in IOS.

Animation View: http://www.jayaprasad.com/prototypes/healthbook/

Animation Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0HkWgmeIlc

can you please suggest me that how to develop this type of list view in android application because there is not such lib which providing this type of animated list view.

Comment any suggestion and link of examples which can help me.

this [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27560442/3713967) asked but no one has given any solution for that so i asking this again if i get any solution so i decided to reopen it by asking this again.

Thanks.

Comment: @Ravi Rupareliya yes i know but no one has answered that question and also too old so.. i post it again

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this lib and customize this lib [CardUI](https://github.com/nadavfima/cardsui-for-android/tree/master/CardsUILib)